# Can you construct a nonagon with 47 rods?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, construction

[Stiv's Diabolical Instruments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110592/75318) now offers a bundle of exactly 47 equal-length rods that can be joined by hinges at their ends – and only the ends – to form planar linkages (i.e. all hinge axes are normal to the plane containing the rods and rod thickness is neglected).

With 35 of these rods you can make [a rigid linkage](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3955860/357390) containing the vertices of a regular heptagon:

[image]

Now you want to do the same for a regular nonagon. But the best known bracing of a regular nonagon uses [51 rods](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0100.html), more than you have from one bundle:

[image]

Nevertheless it is possible to form a rigid linkage containing the vertices of a regular nonagon using only 47 rods by imagining that you have 7 more rods, making a *fully symmetric* ($D_{18}$ symmetry, same as that of the nonagon) rigid linkage with those 54 rods and removing 7 redundant rods. What does the 47-rod linkage look like?

> Searching my MathWorld contributions *will* help (MathWorld Contributors -> Tan).

Comment: “hinge axes are _parallel_ to the plane containing the rods” (emphasis mine -kkm) -- you probably mean _normal_.

Comment: That's a nice problem for a Master's thesis... 

Comment: @kkm The answer can be found under my real-life name on MathWorld... sort of.